# How to flatten a list non-recursively in sml/nj?

Tags: list, sml, smlnj

```
fun flat [] = []   
  | flat (l::ls) = l @ flat ls;
```

This will flatten a list.

Is there a way to non recursively do the same operation? Perhaps with HOFs?

Comment: What's wrong with recursion? avoiding it will make it look more like procedural programming in my opinion

Comment: I wanted to use HOPs perhaps, if possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use high-order function [List.foldr](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list.html):

```
fun flat xs = List.foldr (fn (x, acc) => x @ acc) [] xs
```

As @Andreas said, the function above can be shortened:

```
fun flat xs = List.foldr op@ [] xs
```

Although you would like to implement `flat` as an exercise, [List.concat](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list.html#SIG%3aLIST.concat%3aVAL) in the standard library does exactly the same thing.

Comment: @Dickson: Or even shorter: ``fun flat xs = List.foldr op@ [] xs``. But in fact, the standard library already provides this function under the name ``List.concat``.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg: Thank you. I updated my answer with your suggestions.